# angular 8 getting alternate color on rows that uses ngFor

Tags: css, angular, html-table, ngfor

I am running into issues in getting the alternate rows  with 2 different colors.  I have a JSON data coming from backend, which is a dynamic array of objects. I need to show the data in the table as in the example here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/create-xpkbjm?file=app/app.component.html

The odd, even rule that I find in most Stackoverflow questions doesn't seem to work here.

I would like to show the rows with alternate colors(the rows come as groups). The data should be presented similar to the link in the above stackblitz, but each rows should have alternate color. The odd, even rule only work for each group, but doesn't alternate the color in the table as a whole.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with plain old css,

```
tr:nth-child(2n) {
  background: lightgray;
}
```

You can update the object that you're using to loop over and create the table.

Currently, you're using two loops,

- one over `tbody` with `groups`
- and one over `tr` with `group.events`

Instead, you can create another variable that is a list of events,

```
// app.component.ts
events = this.groups.map(g => g.events).flat();
```

Which simplifies your HTML to,

```
<!-- app.component.html -->
<tr *ngFor="let event of events; index as i">
  <td>
    {{event.event}}
  </td>
</tr>
```

Check on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/create-nm3fda?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

**UPDATE**:

You can track total elements using a `group`/`count` property on each event across the whole object like so,

```js
//app.component.ts
constructor() {
  this.createGroups();
}

createGroups() {
  let count = 0;
  this.groups.forEach(g => {
    g.events.forEach(e => {
      e.group = count++;
    });
  });

  console.log(this.groups);
}
```

And then use `[ngClass]` to bind a css class based on this property,

```
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let group of groups; index as i">
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr *ngIf="i!==0">
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr *ngFor="let event of group.events;" [ngClass]="{'even': event.group % 2 !== 0}">
          <td>{{event.event}} {{event.group}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Updated [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/create-nm3fda?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: thanks for the response @painotpi , but this doesnot work for the last row and second last row, if you check in my link above, both of them have lightgray. I wish to have alternate color. plus the data is dynamic. https://stackblitz.com/edit/create-xpkbjm?file=app/app.component.css

Comment: If you check my original stackblitz link, the event group should have a blank row above it.  So, If I flatten the array, I doubt, I can create a blank row.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using pure CSS without the need to modify the angular.

```
tbody tr
{
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  color: #fff;
}

tbody tr:nth-child(odd)
{
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: if you can see here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/create-xpkbjm?file=app/app.component.css. last two rows have same color and this is not what I wish to have.